# Custom BDC External Data column errors "No exact match was found"

Tags: external-content-type, custom-bdc, external-data-column

I've created a custom BCD for SharePoint 2010. It works well, i can create a list, view all the items, click on an item and view it.

I am now adding this to a list as an External Data column. The column adds, and the picker works, I can see all that I need. When I select one of the items, however it errors. The field value shows the BCS ID,  __bk82000300030003000300030003006300530063009300, and the error below

> No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for
>   more options. You can also use Select button to choose External Data.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it.

My ReadItem method was using Linq to get me item, but using .Single(). There are duplicate records in my list, so I changed it to .First() and then all is well.

Thanks,

Comment: I think that .FirstOrDefault() will be better. If the sequence is empty .First() throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Set any columna "name" as Title. In sharepoint designer->external content type->fields->select field that you show in associated field